# SESSION_CONTEXT returning NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created this following stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [CheckSecurityContext] AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Fruit varchar(20) = CONVERT(varchar(20), SESSION_CONTEXT(N'FRUIT'))
    SELECT CheckSecurityContext = @Fruit
END
```

and have assigned value and the key like below :

```
EXEC sp_set_session_context N'Fruit',  N'Mango'
```

Then executed the stored procedure:

```
EXEC CheckSecurityContext
```

the current result is `NULL` instead of `Mango`, but when I do a simple SELECT like below :

```
select SESSION_CONTEXT(N'Fruit')
```

The result is `Mango`, I am a little bit confused astThe key value is persistent throughout the session. We can execute the stored procedure multiple times, and it returns the same value in each execution. But I am getting a NULL result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, and obscurely, the SESSION_CONTEXT keys are case-sensitive.  Should be

```
DECLARE @Fruit varchar(20) = CONVERT(varchar(20), SESSION_CONTEXT(N'Fruit'))
```